# PHP - SQL query in loop

Tags: php, sql, loops

I'm working on a login system for a A Level Computing project I'm working on. I'm working on making the registration system more robust from a basic 10 minutes job I did so that I could test the login section, however I have come into some issues in the process.

I'm creating a system where you enter your forename and surname, then it generates a username with the first letter of the forename and then the surname, like "T.Smyth" then adds you to the system. To make it more robust so that if the username is taken it still works I want to make it so that it uses the first 2 characters, then 3, etc. like "Th.Smyth", "Tho.Smyth". However when I add a loop system to do this my SQL just stops working and no error files are made or errors returned. I'm stumped by this and have already started from the ground up to attempt it again.

My code is in a pastebin as I can't get the code thing to work here:
http://pastebin.com/CeLTpZvS

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what caused the issue, but I managed to resolve it. I think it was most likely some sort of spam protection to prevent my SQL server being spammed with requests.